# Why doesn't Oracle throw an "ambiguous column reference" here?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a couple of SQL queries here-

```
WITH emp AS
         (SELECT 1 AS empid, 'Adam' AS ename, 10 AS deptno, 'Broker' AS description FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 2, 'Bob', 20, 'Accountant' FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 3, 'Charles', 30, 'Programmer' FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 4, 'Dan', 10, 'Manager' FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 5, 'Eric', 10, 'Salesman' FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 6, 'Franc', 20, 'Consultant' FROM dual),
     dept AS
         (SELECT 10 AS deptno, 'Accounts' AS dname, 100 employment_type_id FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 20, 'Broking', 100 FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 30, 'Corporate Relations', 200 FROM dual),
     employment_type AS
         (SELECT 100 AS employment_type_id, 'Permanent' AS description FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 200, 'Contract' FROM dual)
/* --- Query 1
select e.ename, d.dname, e.description
  from emp e
       inner join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
       inner join employment_type e on d.employment_type_id = e.employment_type_id
-- */
-- /* Query 2
SELECT e.ename, d.dname, e.description
  FROM employment_type e
       INNER JOIN dept d ON e.employment_type_id = d.employment_type_id
       INNER JOIN emp e ON d.deptno = e.deptno
-- */
;
```

As you can see in both the queries the alias for tables `emp` and `employment_type` are the same, i.e., `e`.

When I select a column by saying `e.description` shouldn't I get an error saying something like

> ambiguous column reference

Morevoer, the result of the two queries is different! In the first, `emp.description` is selected while in the second, `employment_type.description` is selected.

Please let me know why this happens and how the confusion arising from this can be avoided.

Comment: i just see one query has E alias

Comment: Here is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58831/ambiguity-in-left-joins-oracle-only)

Comment: Try to read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246638/oracle-sql-non-unique-table-alias-in-one-select

Comment: As answerrs to @NishantGupta's linked question say, this looks like an Oracle bug - it should surely complain that the alias has been used twice, even if there are no common column names.  The obvious way to avoid this confusion is not to use the same alias twice in a query!

Comment: @BasilBattikhi, one query is commented, the other is not. I had added both them for everyone's reference for what I'm trying to do. Try commenting one query while running the other and you'll see the difference in results. I need to know why Oracle doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @TonyAndrews thanks for the comment and yes, that's the obvious way to avoid it. Yet, many newbie SQL query writers often end up committing this mistake and I don't know how to get them to code right. Meanwhile, I'm looking for any information on open defects pending with Oracle, like their public defect tracking system (which may just be non existent). Do let me know if you find any links :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle SQL never complied fully to any ANSI/ISO SQL Standard. 
For example, it never supported `AS` in the `from` clause:

```
select *from dual AS d; -- fails
```

The current status of compliance ([Oracle Compliance To Core SQL:2011](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_standard_sql003.htm#SQLRF55516) for Oracle 12c) 
shows that various features of ANSI SQL supported mostly partially, for example:

```
...
E031, Identifiers:
    Oracle supports this feature, with the following exceptions:
    ...
```

or,

```
E051, Basic query specification
    Oracle fully supports the following subfeatures:
    ...
```

And while it does not say anything about ambiguous aliases (or *range variables* officially), you may envisage that differences can easily go deeper than stated in the page.

I currently know no way to make Oracle report ambiguity in such cases, but just paying attention to make your aliases distinct is not that hard in my opinion.

You may wonder if ANSI SQL Standard says exactly that duplicate aliases in the same scope are not allowed.
It does, in section *7.6*  of *Part 2, SQL/Foundation* document of SQL:2011 standard. (You can download the draft from [www.wiscorp.com](https://www.wiscorp.com/sql20nn.zip)).
Specifically, in subsection *Syntax Rules, 10)*, it says (I cut it a little):

```
10) Let RV be a range variable that is exposed by TR. Let RV1 be a range variable that is exposed by a <table reference> TR1 that has the same scope clause as TR. 
   a) If RV is a <table name>, then
      i) If RV1 is a <table name>, then RV1 shall not be equivalent to RV.
      ii) Otherwise, RV1 shall not be equivalent to the <qualified identifier> of RV.
   b) Otherwise
      i) If RV1 is a <table name>, then the <qualified identifier> of RV1 shall not be equivalent to RV.
      ii) Otherwise, RV1 shall not be equivalent to RV.
```

Here RV's are variable ranges, and you can see that the last choice applies to the case of two aliases.

We know that major SQL brands implement this check (SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL), so this information should be accurate, despite coming from a draft.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query to get your result:

This is for : to get emp table description

```
/* --- Query 1

select e.ename, d.dname, e.description
  from emp e
       inner join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
       inner join employment_type et on d.employment_type_id = et.employment_type_id
-- */


-- /* Query 2
SELECT e.ename, d.dname, em.description
  FROM employment_type e
       INNER JOIN dept d ON e.employment_type_id = d.employment_type_id
       INNER JOIN emp em ON d.deptno = em.deptno
-- */
```

According to your code:

First query you have use alias 'e' for emp table (as first table) .
so it get description from the first table you have specify(emp table).

Same as for the query 2: 
It refer the table employment_type (as first table)
so it get description from it.